# What fills the new space created during expansion?

Tags: space, expansion

Does it remain void and pushes even more or will virtual particles eventually create normal matter?

Answer (score 2):

It's not the case that something needs to be put in there, it's just that space itself is expanding. So if the bit you are watching expand is void then it will still be void, only bigger - you don't get new space, you just get bigger space.