# Galaxies stay at same place but it's the space that splits the galaxies apart

Tags: galaxy, space, expansion

Galaxies stay at same place but it's the space that splits the galaxies apart. Is my understanding correct?

As per my understanding. Galaxies moving apart at high speed is due to the increase in space between the galaxies (i.e. new space is created between galaxies that push the galaxies apart). That's why it's said that every point in universe is center of the universe because after bigbang space has been created between galaxies and it started splitting the galaxies away.

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: That doesn't  look like the dupe to me. I think there is a duplicate here, but that's not it.

Comment: Space has been expanding since the very start of the Big Bang, long before any stars or galaxies were formed.

Comment: @RoryAlsop No, it doesn't. Your reference is related to direction of the galaxy moving. Whereas this question is related to space between galaxies.

Comment: How about https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/10130/43

Comment: What about this ? https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/32979/do-gravitationally-bound-e-g-orbiting-objects-really-resist-the-expansion-of Or this ? https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/29930/what-fills-the-new-space-created-during-expansion This ? https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/9932/9527

Comment: Maybe this answer helps ? https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/2140/72564